# Form don't return value ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return value form input element but it returns 0 even when value is different.

I apologize if this question is 'trivial'. But it would be a great help if you can provide me with an answer.

Function that should add data to the database:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DodajProizvod(string naziv, int kategorijaId)
{
    Proizvod proizvod = new Proizvod
        {
            KategorijaId = kategorijaId,
            Naziv = naziv
        };

    db.Proizvodi.Add(proizvod);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("VratiProizvode", kategorijaId);
}
```

Model class:

```
public class Proizvod
{
    [Key]
    public int ProizvodId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Unesite Naziv Proizvoda")]
    public string Naziv { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Izaberite Kategoriju")]
    public int KategorijaId { get; set; }
    public Kategorija Kategorija { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="DodajProizvod" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="KategorijaId" name="kategorijaId" value="@ViewBag.kategorijaId" disabled class="form-control" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Naziv" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Naziv" name="naziv" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Naziv" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Dodaj Proizvod" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="VratiProizvode" asp-route-kategorijaId="@ViewBag.kategorijaId">Otkazi</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see in input there is value of 3:

[image]

But when I submit, it returns 0:

[image]

Comment: Post the model back not just the fields.  For example if you have action that displays the form like return View(myModel) then public ActionResult(ModelName myModel) and read the data from there should be filled in.;

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, anyway i have tried it and it returns 0 too.

Comment: Try removing `asp-route-kategorijaId="@ViewBag.kategorijaId"`

Comment: Sorry if i caused confusion, but i have problem with input, input wont retun value. Whatsoever i have no problem with link element that you refer to. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `disabled` attribute with `readonly` in input tag for `KategorijaId`

```html
<input asp-for="KategorijaId" value="@ViewBag.kategorijaId" readonly class="form-control" />
```

Change the `action` to

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DodajProizvod(Proizvod model)
```

Then change the `view` to this.

```
@model Proizvod
<form asp-action="DodajProizvod" method="post" asp-antiforgery="true">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="KategorijaId" value="@ViewBag.kategorijaId" readonly class="form-control" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Naziv" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Naziv" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Naziv" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Dodaj Proizvod" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="VratiProizvode" asp-route-kategorijaId="@ViewBag.kategorijaId">Otkazi</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, i have tried it and its still 0..

Comment: @InsaneShadow I updated my answer and it work successfully

Comment: You're right, i added readonly without deleting disabled. I apologize. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**In Asp .NET Core MVC value of a form's input that's marked as disabled is not being sent to the server. As an alternative you could mark it as readonly with a proper background-color.**

[image]